# Why is a non-competing company I interviewed at not responding to my attempts at communicating in a business context?

Tags: interviewing, communication

In late 2014 I interviewed at a nearby company. The interview went well, but afterward when it came time to discuss compensation, my requirements apparently made the interstitial recruiter angry. The interview was the last I communicated directly with our neighboring company.

Since that interview, my workplace has altered drastically for the better. I have been promoted, and as part of my new job I wanted to reach out to this neighboring company. My boss knows about my interview, so I have no fear of getting in trouble. The neighboring company does not (to my knowledge) compete with us in any space, but we have overlapping competencies, and could imaginably work together on some projects.

Six months ago I contacted their sales department asking if they would like to make some custom components for us. Their sales engineer said he was on the road, but would call me back the next day. I never heard back, and two further calls were left unreturned.

Two months ago I emailed their director of engineering, again without response. I connected with him on LinkedIn, and he accepted my connection. I sent a similar message through LinkedIn, thinking the email kraken might have eaten my original email. No response. I emailed a different engineer at the company. No response.

This strikes me as very unusual behavior. Either this company doesn't want to talk to me personally, or they don't want to talk to my company. The first seems unprofessional. The second seems concerning, as if they plan to enter competition with us.

Am I overthinking this situation? Does this seem to anyone else like an unusual sequence of events? Should I be concerned? Are there any further actions I should take?

Comment: you're spamming them

Answer (score 9):

> Am I overthinking this situation?

Yes

> Does this seem to anyone else like an unusual sequence of events?

Yes, you seem to be working too hard to give them your business.

> Should I be concerned?

Nope.  Their business problem(turning down potential revenue) is not your concern.

> Are there any further actions I should take?

Nope.  Except for moving on and researching another company that values your business.  There are plenty out there.

I don't think there's anything more to be gained by pursuing this.  If this situation had anything to do with your compensation demand/request(when you interviewed w/them) they need to understand that it's ok to disagree and still be able to move on and be professional.

Comment: Perfect.  It is their problem - move on.